# Request dangerous permission for wear os watchface

Tags: android-service, android-permissions, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I'm trying to create a watch face using some data. However, I need access to ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to get the user's location. From the sample provided [here](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/main/WatchFaceKotlin), the watch face is launched as a service and permission's cannot be requested from a service. What would be the best approach to develop a watch face that requires dangerous permissions and will require to make network calls?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it for a watch face... but you can start an activity once the face is set to request the permission...

Comment: From what method or place would you launch the activity in the service?

Comment: If it's a permission you will need right away, call it on onCreate (or similar)... if it is something not "essential", required just for a specific feature,  before calling the feature you can: check if you have permission, if not you call ur activity